# auto text messaging syncing

Tags: iphone, sdk

What I want this App to be able to do, is to be able to allow the individual copy all the text messages on his/ her phone and then send them to their profile on the website that I am creating. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the user copying from the SMS app to your app via cut and paste yes. But I think you mean can your app programmatically grab all of someone's text messages and the answer to that is no.